# Xcode Array to TableView

Tags: arrays, xcode, tableview

I was making a simple application that has a button. When clicked, it moves to another `ViewController`. As I load the new `ViewController` with a table view in it, I access the server that outputs a string that I place into an array. In the did load function, the Array was successfully read. BUt when I place the array to be processed by the table functions, the program shuts down..

here is my code..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *psalmCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"psalmcell"];

    //create a cell
    if(psalmCell == nil)
    {
        psalmCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
                     initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                     reuseIdentifier:@"psalmcell"];
    }
    //fill contents
    psalmCell.textLabel.text = @"Psalm";

    psalmCell.textLabel.text = [listItemsR objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    //return
    return psalmCell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return listItemsR.count;

}


- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sample.stie.com/sample.php"];
    NSString *response_string = @"";
    //
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"retrievePending" forKey:@"command"];
    [request startSynchronous];
    response_string = [request responseString];
    NSLog(@"JSON : %@",response_string);


    listItemsR = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:listItemsR];
    listItemsR = [response_string componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];

    NSInteger arCount = listItemsR.count;

    NSLog(@"%d",arCount);

    for(NSInteger i=1; i<arCount; i++){
        NSString *final = [listItemsR objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"%@",final);
    }
    [listItemsR release];
}
```

PLease do help me!! Im really confused here.. ^^,, Thanks!!! By the way Im using Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.x